# Class 'Base_Controller' not found

Tags: laravel-4

i am a beginner to laravel 4 framework.can any body help me why the following code showing an error when i am running it in the browser.

authors.php in controller

```
<?php
class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller{
    public $restful = true;
    public function get_index(){
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
 Route::get('authors',array('uses' => 'authors@index'));
```

can anybody suggest me a good video tutorial to learn laravel 4 clearly

Comment: have you done a php artisan dump-autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending the wrong class, based on the fact you are using laravel version 4.

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
```

Comment: the above code is according to this.in this video tutorial its working,but in mine its not

Comment: The youtube video is about laravel version 3.

Comment: can you please suggest me a gud video tutorial for laravel version 4,from where i can begin with

Comment: Laracast has great video's, the service is paid, but Jeffrey also posted some free video's, available at https://laracasts.com/tags/free